# Get data from component to another page view

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vue-component, pass-data

There is one component "TableFields.vue", and two view files "Home.vue" and "Statistics.vue".
In component, I have `changes: []` variable under `data()` object.

```
  data () {
    return {
      startStopA: true,
      startStopB: true,
      initialValueA: 3,
      initialValueB: 3,
      randomNumbersArray: [],
      randomSignA: '+',
      randomSignB: '+',
      signsArray: ['+', '-'],
      intervalA: null,
      intervalB: null,
      changes: []
    }
  },
```

That `changes` array dynamically gets object from `calculationsA()` function.

```
    calculationsA () {
      this.randomSignA = this.signsArray[
        Math.floor(Math.random() * this.signsArray.length)
      ]
      this.randomSignA === '+'
        ? (this.initialValueA += this.randomNumbersArray[0])
        : (this.initialValueA -= this.randomNumbersArray[0])
      const d = new Date()
      // console.log(d.toLocaleTimeString())
      // console.log(this.randomNumbersArray[0])
      // this.changes.push(this.randomNumbersArray[0])
      // this.changes.push(d.toLocaleTimeString())
      // console.log(this.changes)
      const newChange = {}
      newChange.field = 'A'
      newChange.value = this.randomNumbersArray[0]
      newChange.time = d.toLocaleTimeString()
      this.changes.push(newChange)
    },
```

How do I pass `changes: []` from `TableField.vue` component to `Statistics.vue`page, in order to code dynamic table with `changes` array objects data. I am not sure, do I need to create new component or this can be done without it. Basically, this is the working code from the `TableField.vue` component that is implemented for testing purposes and can be seen from `Home.vue` which is root url.

```
    <div class="statistics">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th>Field</th>
          <th>Value</th>
          <th>Time</th>
        </tr>
        <tr v-for="item in changes" :key="item.value">
          <td>{{ item.field }}</td>
          <td>{{ item.value }}</td>
          <td>{{ item.time }}</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I need that code to work at `Statistics.vue` page.
Here is the [link](https://gitlab.com/srdjan-milic/factory-worldwide) to gitlab repo for better convenience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User "async" from discord vue chat has solved this for me.
Solution was a bit complicated and required a changes to few files.
Refer to gitlab repo if you are curious to find out more about it, because I can't document it here due to its complexity.

Answer (score 0):

According to me, the better solution should be using Vuex (https://vuex.vuejs.org/) that permits you to store data in sharing point called store.

Alternatively you can use events as documented here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Binding-Native-Events-to-Components

Answer (score 0):

You can import `TableField.vue` in `Statistics.vue` and pass `changes: []` as props.

Comment: If I import `TableFields.vue` in `Statistics.vue` I will had to declare it in the template code block `<TableFields /> right,  which will end up so that `Statistics.vue` page will be the same as `Home.vue` page. Could you give me code example please exactly how I can achieve that things with props. Where I should put the `props` declaration and how I can pass it to `Statistics.vue`. Just to pass `changes: []` values. i have been trying since yesterday to solve this. Please keep in mind that `TableFields.vue` component is declared in `Home.vue`, so `Home.vue` = `TableFields.vue`.